# PostgreSQL grant access to table

Tags: postgresql

I have user1 and user2 users in PostgreSQL. I have created a database and a scheme called `data` in PostgreSQL.

In the database, I have executed the following statements:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA data GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO user1;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA data GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO user2;
```

I logged in as user1 and created tables in data schema, then I logged in as user2, and couldn't select * from table1 using user2 credentials.

Is there any way I can create table (future) and give access to user1 & user2, not just the owner of the table?

I am currently using PostgreSQL 13.

Comment: Which user did you use to log in when you ran those ALTER statements?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I login as postgres user to execute the ALTER statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you wrote the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` statement, *it applies to tables created by the user that ran the statement*.

To change the default privileges for tables created by `user1`, run

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE user1 IN SCHEMA data GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO user2;
```

Comment: Thanks Laurenz, for the info. But if I have a list of users/roles, can I ask on how can I do it?

Comment: If all those users create tables, you need a lot of `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` statements. There is no way around that. Try to automatize.

Answer (score -1):

you may need to specify schema before select * from **data.**table1 using user2 credentials.